# How to show animation which is in global space to local space in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]I have tried to show animation in local space page but I am unable to do that. When I run my scene, animation is played in global space but my requirement is need to show that animation in local spac page. How can we do that. I have tried by changing their converting animation position from global to local position and assigned to it but not luck. Please suggest any idea. Thank you in advance.

I have tried in fallowing manner.

```
 var winAnimation = Instantiate(myanimation);

 var localPosition = winAnimation.transform.InverseTransformVector (winAnimation.transform.position);

 winAnimation.transform.localPosition = localPosition;
```

Comment: What component are you using to play the animation?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have used animator component for playing animation. I have updated my question with adding myanimation prefab inspector window. Then you get clear idea about that.

Comment: What type is `myanimation` ?

Comment: There myanimation is prefab name. I have create one object in global space and adding sprite renderer and animator to that object and make it as a prefab.

Comment: Can you show where it is declared an how? That's all I need to know

Comment: In my script I have taken a 'myanimation' game object and assign value from scene. Here I have assigned created prefab to the 'myanimation' and instatiate that prefab for playing animation.